# Explode URL parameters

Tags: php, regex, laravel, php-5.6

I've got a search function in my website and I wanted to make seo-friendly links, so I decided to convert GET query string from:

```
http://example.com/search?category=example&subcategory=mycategory&region=2 //and other parameters
```

To:

```
http://example.com/search/{parameters}/{string-for-seo?}/{string-for-seo2?}/ //etc.
```

Where `{parameters}` is a string like that: `c3s34r55p21`.

The purpose of the string is to compact the parameters.

*c3 = category id n.3,
s34 = subcategory id n.34*

And so on.

The problem is that I don't know how to explode that strange string to an array in order to get parameters.

```
[
   'c' => 3
   's' => 34
   'r' => 55
]
```

Comment: `c3s34r55p21` is the exact opposite of "SEO-friendly".

Comment: Please check [this demo](https://ideone.com/zX3OFP). Does it help?

Comment: @mario `/search/c3s34r55p21` is not seo-friendly but  `/search/c3s34r55p21/new-york/car-service` yes.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew tomorrow i'll try and tell you. thank you for now

Comment: Cryptic/numberic values don't really benefit readability, even if there's an ignored slug afterwards. Anyway, `(\d+)` captures numbers in a regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you're looking for

```
$input = "c3s34r55p21";

$array = preg_match_all('/([a-z])(\d*)/', $input, $matches);
/*
var_export($array);
echo "\n";
var_export($matches);
echo "\n";
*/
$result = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
var_export($result);
echo "\n";
```